# Pass array values into foreach and finally another variable?

Tags: php, variables, global-variables

In PHP, what's the best practice for dealing with a loop in a variable? Let me explain.

I have a file called index.php which contains the following:

```
<?php 
$SELECT_INDUSTRY = array("Industry1", "Industry2", "Industry3");
require_once('form.inc');
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php echo $FORM_FIELD_INDUSTRY ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I then have a second file called form.inc:

```
<?php
$FORM_FIELD_INDUSTRY = '<select><option value=>Select an Industry</option>'.$INDUSTRY.'</select>';
?>
```

Here's what is needed. I'd like to pass over the array values that are entered, into a foreach to process the array and spit out the `<option></option>` code. Here's an example:

```
foreach ($SELECT_INDUSTRY as $INDUSTRY) {
echo '<option value="$INDUSTRY">$INDUSTRY</option>';
}
```

So this function would build my select options based on the array values. This works, but how would I be able to then pass the total values into a variable that I've defined in the form.inc file above? In the form.inc file, I have $INDUSTRY as the variable, which I suppose needs some sort of return from the other function. This may also need global variables to pass between functions if it comes to it. Is there a better way of handling this?

My end goal is to have the variable $FORM_FIELD_INDUSTRY which spits out the foreach function based on the array values.

**SOLUTION**

The solution is listed below, but for anyone coming across this, here is what I did:

**index.php**

```
<?php 
$SELECT_INDUSTRY = array("Industry1", "Industry2", "Industry3");
$FORM_SELECT_SIZE = ''; 
require_once('form.inc');
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php get_options( $FORM_FIELD_INDUSTRY ) ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**form.inc**

```
<?php
function get_options( $arr = array() ) {
    global $FORM_SELECT_SIZE;
    echo '<select id="industry" class="'.$FORM_SELECT_SIZE.'"><option value=>Select an Industry</option>';
    foreach( $arr as $option ) {
        echo '<option>'.$option.'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select></div></div>';
}
$FORM_FIELD_INDUSTRY = $SELECT_INDUSTRY;
?>
```

Pretty simple solution for passing values between the function, and variables.

Comment: Why aren't you just using a function with the foreach in there?

Comment: I thought about that, but I couldn't get the final code to work right. I suppose I could break out the foreach into a function, but then how would I call that function within a variable declaration? I'm not sure I can do that.

Comment: You can pass variables as arguments to your function, look at the code in the answer below to see how.

Comment: Looks like this did the trick. I've updated my original question to show the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use a function to build the options and return it like so:

```
function get_options( $arr = array() ) {
    echo '<select>';
    foreach( $arr as $option ) {
        echo '<option>'.$option.'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
}
```

And then in your HTML you could call it like this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php get_options( $SELECT_INDUSTRY ); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

So if I were to take the code you gave us on top and combined it all it would look like this:

```
<?php 
$SELECT_INDUSTRY = array("Industry1", "Industry2", "Industry3");
require_once('form.inc');
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php get_options( $SELECT_INDUSTRY ); ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php
function get_options( $arr = array() ) {
    echo '<select>';
    foreach( $arr as $option ) {
        echo '<option>'.$option.'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
}
?>
```

Comment: I think this actually solved my issue. Testing it right now, will post up the results.

Comment: This solution worked for my needs. I'll edit my original to plug in the changes of what I did.